# How to add background color in boostrap 5.2?

Tags: html, css

I want to add background color when using boostrap 5.2 , but it seemed like it is not working at all.Even if I used CSS to add background color or using bg-primary for example , nothing happen.

I want to add background color when using bootstrap 5.

My code:

```
footer { 
 margin-top: 160%; 
 width: 100%; 
 background-color: #09249e !important;
}
```

Comment: can you share the code to be able to help you

Comment: footer{
    margin-top: 160%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #09249e !important;
    
}

Comment: try to add class for that tag and use it like that footer.className then apply your style

Comment: and also make sure from inspect element, there is no styles overwritten on your style

Answer (score -1):

Did you import Bootstrap styles?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="bg-primary" >
  This text have blue background.
</div>
```

Comment: I did this but nothing happen

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS code in the question?